# How does marking classes as [Serializable] work in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I made a class called MyData and marked it with [Serializable], but it doesn't seem to work...

Here's MyData.cs:

```
namespace Forms_Bot_Rebuild
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyData
    {
        private String _Email;
        private String _Password;
        private String _WorldId;
        public MyData(string email, string password, string worldid)
        {
            _Email = email;
            _Password = password;
            _WorldId = worldid;
        }
        public string Email
        { get { return _Email; } set { _Email = value; } }
        public string Password
        { get { return _Password; } set { _Password = value; } }
        public string WorldId
        { get { return _WorldId; } set { _WorldId = value; } }
    }
}
```

Here's Form1.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyData data = new MyData(boxEmail.Text, boxPass.Text, boxWorldId.Text);
    string objectNode = Serialize.ToJsonString(data);
    File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\LoginData.json", objectNode);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    object myData;
    myData = Serialize.Deserialize<MyData>(new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"\LoginData.json", FileMode.Open));
    boxEmail.Text = data.Email;
    boxPass.Text = data.Password;
    boxWorldId.Text = data.WorldId;
}
```

Here's Serialize.cs:

```
public class Serialize
{
    public static StreamReader ToStreamReader(object o)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(o.GetType());
        ser.WriteObject(stream, o);
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        return sr;
    }
    public static string ToJsonString(object o)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(o.GetType());
        ser.WriteObject(stream, o);
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    public static object Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        stream.Position = 0;
        T t = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Also, this code was given to me by a friend, so I asked him. He couldn't understand it too. I asked another friend, who, in my opinion, knew decent C#, but he couldn't fix it too.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Additional information: Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
[DataContract]
```

instead of

```
[Serializable]
```

and mark all the properties with

```
[DataMember]
```

(but funnily, on my PC works even with `Serializable`, only it serializes fields instead of properties... Mmmh I see someone else noticed it: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/27/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer)

Note that `Deserialize` could have this signature:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
```

and you should close streams after using them:

```
MyData myData;

using (var fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"\LoginData.json""LoginData.json", FileMode.Open))
{
    myData = (MyData)Serialize.Deserialize<MyData>(fs);
}
```

If instead you really want to know what you wrote in the title:

Each serialization class/method look for "its" serialization attributes (at this time there are at least three families of attributes in Microsoft .NET: `[Serializable]`, the `[Xml*]` family, the `[DataContract]`. Plus if you use JSON.NET there are its `[Json*]` attributes. Stop. So depending on the class/method you want to use to serialize your data, you have to know which attributes it will look for.

Comment: Using the [Serializable] attribute is perfectly fine its just Opt-Out instead of Opt-In.

Comment: @BenediktSchroeder By default it serializes only fields, not properties, so I wouldn't call it "opt-out". I would call it "fields-only unless opt-out (fields) + opt-in (properties)"